# Stress test cases for web application

Tags: stress-testing, testcase

What other stress test cases are there other than finding out the maximum number of users allowed to login into the web application before it slows down the performance and eventually crashing it?

Answer (score 1):

This question is hard to answer thoroughly since it's too broad.

Anyway many stress tests depend on the type and execution flow of your workload. There's an [entire subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory) dedicated (as a graduate course) to queue theory and resources optimization. Most of the things can be summarized as follows:

> if you have a resource (be it a gpu, cpu, memory bank, mechanical or
>   solid state disk, etc..), it can serve a number of users/requests per
>   second and takes an X amount of time to complete one unit of work.
>   Make sure you don't exceed its limits.

Some systems can also be studied with a probabilistic approach ([Little's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law) is one of the most fundamental rules in these cases)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of reasons for load/performance testing, many of which may not be important to your project goals. For example:
- What is the performance of a system at a given load? (load test)
- How many users the system can handle and still meet a specific set of performance goals? (load test)
- How does the performance of a system changes over time under a certain load? (soak test)
- When will the system will crash under increasing load? (stress test)
- How does the system respond to hardware or environment failures? (stress test)

I've got a post on some common [motivations for performance testing](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/2010/09/the-purpose-of-load-testing/) that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out your web analytics data and see what people are actually doing.
It's not enough to simply simulate X number of users logging in. Find the scenarios that represent the most common user activities (anywhere between 2 to 20 scenarios).

Also, make sure you're not just hitting your cache on reads. Add some randomness / diversity in the requests.
I've seen stress tests where all the users were requesting the same data which won't give you real world results.